# Projector without Windows detection as monitor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing software for a machine that my company is making and need to figure out how to send images to the projector without Windows detecting the projector and making it a monitor.

Having the projector appear as a monitor means locking Windows 7 will result in our displayed image disappearing and becoming the lock screen.

How do I remove the projector as a recognized monitor but still send images to it? Maybe I need to implement a hardware change and then modify my software to write to some third party device?

C#/.NET 4.5.1/WinForms

Comment: sounds like the question really is - how can i prevent the display of windows lock screen? Just disable screen lock.

Comment: ^^^minus 1 point... Hopefully someone knows how to do what I need.  We would like for people to be able to lock the computer when they walk away from it.  Security is important.

Comment: you didnt say that. So describe exactly what you need. Are there 2 monitors, one is screen one is projector. It sounded like you needed to set up a system with only the projector

Comment: seems like there are commercial products https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/ScreenSavers/

Comment: or set the screen saver to be a blank screen